# Fixing JSON highlighting refresh

Tags: syntax-highlighting

When I manually edit `json` files, I end up with red boxes falsely alerting me to syntax problems until I take manual action to refresh those lines.

I start with a file with a key/value pair:

```
{
    "key1":"value1"
}
```

If I want to add another key/value pair, my first keystrokes are <kbd>End</kbd><kbd>a</kbd><kbd>,</kbd>.

At this point, the comma is highlighted RED. This makes sense because it is a syntax error. to have a comma with nothing afterwards.

Next I add the new key/value:

<kbd>Enter</kbd>    `"key2":"value2"`

[image]

The red over the comma persists until I refresh that line by temporarily adding a character after it, or reloading `vim`.  That significantly increases the number of keystrokes I need when editing files.  It also means I tend to ignore legitimate mistakes that I would prefer to address right away.

How can I get the syntax highlighting to auto-update for the previous line?

---

Here's `vim --version` if relevant.

```
VIM - Vi IMproved 8.2 (2019 Dec 12, compiled Oct 01 2021 01:51:08)
Included patches: 1-2434
Extra patches: 8.2.3402, 8.2.3403, 8.2.3409, 8.2.3428
Modified by team+vim@tracker.debian.org
Compiled by team+vim@tracker.debian.org
Huge version without GUI.  Features included (+) or not (-):
+acl               -farsi             +mouse_sgr         +tag_binary
+arabic            +file_in_path      -mouse_sysmouse    -tag_old_static
+autocmd           +find_in_path      +mouse_urxvt       -tag_any_white
+autochdir         +float             +mouse_xterm       -tcl
-autoservername    +folding           +multi_byte        +termguicolors
-balloon_eval      -footer            +multi_lang        +terminal
+balloon_eval_term +fork()            -mzscheme          +terminfo
-browse            +gettext           +netbeans_intg     +termresponse
++builtin_terms    -hangul_input      +num64             +textobjects
+byte_offset       +iconv             +packages          +textprop
+channel           +insert_expand     +path_extra        +timers
+cindent           +ipv6              -perl              +title
-clientserver      +job               +persistent_undo   -toolbar
-clipboard         +jumplist          +popupwin          +user_commands
+cmdline_compl     +keymap            +postscript        +vartabs
+cmdline_hist      +lambda            +printer           +vertsplit
+cmdline_info      +langmap           +profile           +virtualedit
+comments          +libcall           -python            +visual
+conceal           +linebreak         -python3           +visualextra
+cryptv            +lispindent        +quickfix          +viminfo
+cscope            +listcmds          +reltime           +vreplace
+cursorbind        +localmap          +rightleft         +wildignore
+cursorshape       -lua               -ruby              +wildmenu
+dialog_con        +menu              +scrollbind        +windows
+diff              +mksession         +signs             +writebackup
+digraphs          +modify_fname      +smartindent       -X11
-dnd               +mouse             -sound             -xfontset
-ebcdic            -mouseshape        +spell             -xim
+emacs_tags        +mouse_dec         +startuptime       -xpm
+eval              +mouse_gpm         +statusline        -xsmp
+ex_extra          -mouse_jsbterm     -sun_workshop      -xterm_clipboard
+extra_search      +mouse_netterm     +syntax            -xterm_save
   system vimrc file: "$VIM/vimrc"
     user vimrc file: "$HOME/.vimrc"
 2nd user vimrc file: "~/.vim/vimrc"
      user exrc file: "$HOME/.exrc"
       defaults file: "$VIMRUNTIME/defaults.vim"
  fall-back for $VIM: "/usr/share/vim"
Compilation: gcc -c -I. -Iproto -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -Wdate-time -g -O2 -ffile-prefix-map=/build/vim-DtwDbo/vim-8.2.2434=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=1 
Linking: gcc -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now -Wl,--as-needed -o vim -lm -ltinfo -lselinux -lacl -lattr -lgpm -ldl
```

Comment: I can't reproduce that problem on Vim 9

Comment: I can verify with a 8.1.3741 (debian). But this seems to be fixed with the latest syntax version from the [vim repository](https://github.com/vim/vim/blob/master/runtime/syntax/json.vim). Try that please.

Comment: I can reproduce on Vim 8.1 but not on Vim 8.2. It looks like a bug of Vim 8.1 that has been solved in 8.2 (the behavior in 9.0 is again slightly different but very acceptable to me). In Vim 9.0 you have to move the cursor to another line to get the refresh.

Comment: Working on `git clone https://github.com/vim/vim.git` right now.

Comment: Tried in `vim` 8.2. and `vim` 9.0 and see the same behaviour in both.  I see Vivan's work-around now.  If I move the cursor to one of the closing bracket of the object, the highlight refreshes.  That will work for me.  Thanks.

Comment: It's curious that others cannot reproduce, but you can. I suggest checking [How to debug my vimrc](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/2003/10604) in case something may be interfering.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting with Vim 8.2 when you move the cursor the section errors are reevaluated and no editions are needed to get rid of the errors.